# How to move the wordpress template style.css file in another folder?

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, cookieless, pagespeed

I would like to follow one of Page Speed's recommendation: [Serve static content from a cookieless domain](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/speed/page-speed/docs/request.html#ServeFromCookielessDomain). So I need to move the *style.css* file away from the default template folder and put it in my cookieless domain.

How do I notice wordpress for this change?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style.css is ultimately called in the header file of a wordpress template. Simply changing the location call in your templates header to the one where your new styles.css file is located should do the trick.

Comment: Since this question is related to WordPress, this solution will not work. WordPress mandatorily requires `style.css` in root of the theme folder. However, OP may add a second css file and include all styles within that file. This second css file may be kept on a CDN and it's location can be called in the `header` as @awats suggested.

Comment: @John I assume you're referring to the wp_enqueue_style method of calling style.css which looks in the root by default, in which case for CDN usage I would NOT recommend a second stylesheet, but instead deregister the existing default CSS hook and point to the new one. A CDN plugin worth its salt will be able to pick up on this and point accordingly away from the local server and to it's CDN counterpart. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_style

Comment: Well I'm not referring to wp_enqueque_style method. Let me take the example of `Twenty Twelve` theme. It has `style.css` in the root of the theme folder. This file contains commented section at the beginning that tells WordPress what theme it is. If that commented section or the `style.css` file itself containing the commented section were not there in the root folder of the theme, WordPress would not know how to load the theme. The rest of the file contains the CSS that controls the styling of the theme. As a solution to OP's problem, he can leave the `style.css` in the theme...

Comment: ...root folder with the commented section at the beginning intact. He can cut the rest of the CSS code from the file and move it into a separate file and host the new file elsewhere. If you have a WordPress install lying around then just move the `style.css` file and go to WP Admin > Appearance > Themes and check. WordPress would have automatically defaulted to a different theme. http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

OR you could leave everything where it is and set up a sub-domain (say http://static.example.com) and using CNAME in your DNS have that point to your www/root so that any existing file path can be called using that new sub-domain. As long as none of the resource using that sub-domain set cookies then your are achieving the same effect of using a separate (cookie less) domain. See http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/static-cookieless-domain/ for a full run down.